# Using \mathsection in the chapter

Tags: sectioning, formatting

How can I use LaTeX to get the result like the following picture?

[image]

In this picture, `$\mathsection{1} Hình thang và hình bình hành$` is the title of the first section. If I use `\mathsection` and `\section`, then the result is

[image]

My question is: What is the code that gives me the result like the first picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\@makechapterhead`, `\@makeschapterhead` and `\@sect` to obtain the desired representation for the headings (using a package like `titlesec` here is not possible since it's not compatible with the AMS document classes):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{\global\topskip 5.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\bfseries\centering
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \leavevmode \hskip-\leftskip
      \rlap{\vbox to\z@{\vss
          \centerline{\normalsize\mdseries
              \@xp{\scshape{\chaptername}}\enspace\thechapter}
          \vskip 2pc}}\hskip\leftskip\fi
     \normalfont\scshape#1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\global\topskip 7.5pc\relax
  \begingroup
  \fontsize{\@xivpt}{18}\normalfont\scshape\centering
  #1\par \endgroup
  \skip@34\p@ \advance\skip@-\normalbaselineskip
  \vskip\skip@ }
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
 \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
   \let\@svsec\@empty
 \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@svsec{\ifnum#2<\@m
       \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
         \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space}\fi
       \@nx\textup{%
         \csname the#1\endcsname.}\enspace
    }%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup\ifnum#2=1 \noindent\textbf{\S}\fi#6\relax% NEW
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
  \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       \@addpunct.}%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Numbered Section}
\section*{Test Unnumbered Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I customize the word Chapter since in my original file when I type `chapter` it gave me "Chương"(which is chapter in my native language). But when I add your titleformat, it gave me Chapter rather than "Chương". So how can I customize your titleformat command to keep the word "Chương" ?

Comment: @Nguyễn Duy Khánh which document class are you using?  Are you loading the babel package?  If so, with what language option?

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh Replace `\chaptertitlename` with `\chaptername` in my code; this should give you "Chương" again; if not, let me know to find a solution.